# Follow-up to The Red Queen by Matt Ridley?

Tags: genetics, book-recommendation, sexual-selection

I just finished reading *The Red Queen: Sex and the evolution of human nature* by Matt Ridley. Since this book is over 20 years old, I was wondering if more recent research made part of the book obsolete or inaccurate in some way. If so, would you have a recommendation for a recent book that would be a good complement to it?

Comment: Which part of the book? Which theory? I upvoted, but also vote to close because your question is unclear

Comment: Any part of the book, really. I was just wondering if any part of the book needed to be updated, I guess that would have been a clearer question.

Comment: This question is unfortunately too broad. Nobody is going to read the whole and search every single subject to see if there is need for updates.

Comment: My question was aimed at people who already know the book and the field. Maybe that's too narrow a target.

Comment: I haven't read the book, but in the context of parasite-host co-evolution, RQH-style thinking is [very common](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=red+queen+hypothesis).